# Introducing a new keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard-layout

How and where can I ask introducing of a new keyboard layout (ideally for Linux generally)? I have created an own layout for Czech with support for Esperanto (the default Ubuntu option "add Esperanto characters (supersigno)" leads to some problems for removing some useful signs from the Czech keyboard) and I think it would be useful for the other users as well.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a launchpad account, and you will need to propose a merge here

https://code.launchpad.net/ubuntu

It might be best to also hop into #ubuntu in Freenode, and ask for directions on how to do this.